# Session related question - opening browser with multiple tabs

Tags: session

We are having a situation wherein the users are trying to open URLs in the same browser with multiple tabs, while doing that the session variables which store unique identifiers are overwritten.

Is there some setting which can help in overcoming this problem?

Comment: Does any one know if there is any browser setting that can help achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Per default, there is no way to have different sessions in the same browser window. The sessions are always shared trough all tabs. If two different Sessions are enough, you could use a privat/incognito browser window.

A other solution could be to use HTML 5 SessionStorage for your variables. But this works only for your own variables: Craft CMS use normal sessions/cookies. You can find further informations about your topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368653/how-to-differ-sessions-in-browser-tabs.

Comment: Thank you for your response - this makes me double sure that problem cannot be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I personally user http://www.browserjet.com, it allows you to have different session per tab and also comes with built-in VPN.